# Adjusting UITableView height when ad is received/not received

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, admob, nslayoutconstraint

I am using Admob as an Ad provider. I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` which is set in the Storyboard to use the whole width and height of the controller.

When an Ad is received the following occurs:

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)Adview {

    if (bannerView_.hidden) {
        bannerView_.hidden = NO;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        // Final frame of ad should be docked to bottom of screen
        Adview.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height -
                                  Adview.frame.size.height,
                                  Adview.frame.size.width,
                                  Adview.frame.size.height);
    }];
```

This updates the frame of the Adview and makes it show at the bottom of the screen, working as expected.

The issue I have is with the `UITableView` frame. If I update the frame in the same method it appears to update again I believe from the previously set constraints on the table view in the Storyboard.

What would be the correct way to change the constraints/frame of the `UITableView` so that if an Ad is received or not the relevant changes apply.

Receive - `-(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)Adview didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {`
Failure - `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)Adview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to layout your view with the ad frame showing. Have a constraint between the TableView and the adView and then another between the adView and the bottom layout guide. Set an outlet to the bottom constraint.

Then in your code, instead of adjusting frames, set the constant property of the bottom constraint appropriately. Set it to 0 to show the ad, set it to -50 (or your ad fame height) to hide.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.adViewConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.adView.hidden = NO;
}
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Now your tableView should automatically size itself as the adView is hidden or shown.

Comment: Thanks - I can setup the bannerView in the storyboard and correct the layout there. However, when it is loaded the adview shows at the bottom before an ad is received. How do I add/update the appropriate constraint you mention?

Comment: In your ViewDidLoad method, set the constant to -50 (or your ad frame height).

Comment: My question is... If I store the constraint as an outlet what property of the outlet should I be updating to update the bottom layout guide part?

Comment: the constant property of the constraint. I've adjusted my answer a little to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, so I have added the view (bannerView) and set a constraint to the bottom layout guide. Also set this to -50 for when the view loads so it is off screen. However, when I log out the bannerView frame in viewDidLoad I get 0,0,320,50 which suggests it is at the top and not off screen at the bottom?

Comment: Verify that bottom constraint is to bottom layout guide. I've found that if I control drag to create the constraint, it often does bottom of view to Top layout guide. Not what you want. If you select the adView and then click the add constraints button, you can easily add the constraint.

Comment: The constraint is called 'Vertical Space - (-50) - Bottom Layout Guide - Banner View'

Comment: what happens when it runs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46169/discussion-between-stuartm-and-aaron-bratcher)

Comment: In the end it was too difficult and was wasting too much time trying to resolve this. I found out how to correctly resize the banner view on orienation and added some constraints if an ad is being shown. It appears to be a lot more complex to add the animation when the view can often change size and initially needs to be off screen. Thanks for your help on this.